# Cannot login to a page with session.post(URL, data=payload)

Tags: python, authentication, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to automatically login with python requests to a page to download a file every hour, but i haven't had any luck with it.

The page is this one: https://www.still-fds.com/fleetmanager/login/dercomaq

i'm using the Session object like this:

```
import requests

login_URL = 'https://www.still-fds.com/fleetmanager/login/dercomaq'

next_URL = 'https://www.still-fds.com/fleetmanager/pages/reports/vehicle.xhtml'

#(these arent the real username and password, I use the real ones in my code)
payload = {"j_idt181:username": "User", "j_idt181:password": "Password"}


with requests.Session() as ses:
    ses.get(login_URL) #I get a JSESSIONID cookie here
    
    ses.post(login_URL, data = payload) #I send the login request
    
    r = ses.get(next_URL) #I try accessing the next page after login

    with open('login-test.html', 'wb') as f: #writing the HTML i get back to a file so I can preview it
        f.write(r.content)
```

However when I check the preview if the next page, it always redirects/shows me the login page
I've also tried sending a more complete payload, copying everything that gets sent in the normal login request, like this

```
payload = {
'javax.faces.partial.ajax': 'true',
'javax.faces.source':'j_idt181:j_idt190',
'javax.faces.partial.execute': '@all',
'j_idt181:j_idt190': 'j_idt181:j_idt190',
'j_idt181': 'j_idt181',
'j_idt181:username': 'User',
'j_idt181:password': 'Password',
'javax.faces.ViewState': '-4453297688092219000:-1561371993877484606 '
}
```

And I've tried with copying the request headers:

```
#I replace the JSESSIONID cookie for the one that I'm given in the first get request
req_header = {
 'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01'
,'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
,'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
,'Connection': 'keep-alive'
,'Content-Length': '287'
,'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
,'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=U27BXdHsu+EXITX-QfUGkmqW; clientId=dercomaq' 
,'Faces-Request': 'partial/ajax'
,'Host': 'www.still-fds.com'
,'Origin': 'https://www.still-fds.com'
,'Referer': 'https://www.still-fds.com/fleetmanager/login/dercomaq'
,'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty'
,'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors'
,'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin'
,'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'
,'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
```

However I never get the ckientId cookie (I've tried manually giving it a clientId cookie, since it's always 'dercomaq', but it doesn't help either)

All of this works very easily when using Selenium and ChromeDriver, but because of web app constraints I can't use that

Comment: A bit tangential to your question, but you mentioned it works "very easily when using Selenium and ChromeDriver", but then go on to make the contradictory statement "because of web app constrains I can't use that". Can you explain that a bit better?

Comment: It is very easy to do what i want to do (login to the page, fill a form, download a file) because instead of getting into the nitty gritty of requests, i just emulate user inputs in a ChromeDriver browser. However, my boss wants to deploy this code to an Azure webapp, and after investigating a bit, Azure doesnt have the capabilities to run a webdriver program. Thus, i can't use Selenium

Comment: @Franss22 Your `'javax.faces.ViewState'` value is not same as mine. I would suggest you to scrape the actual value from the web page, and then using that value in the post request.